# Add validation for empty inputs to current PHP Login form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I currently have a form that checks if the username and password exist and logs you and redirects you to the homepage. However if you leave the email and password section blank, you also are able to log into the site. I'm looking to add some sort of validation to avoid someone from just using empty input variables.

This is what I have...

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'config.php';
$email ="";
$userpassword ="";
$errors = 0;

$emailError ="";
$passwordError ="";

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
 header("Location: home.php");
}
if(isset($_POST['loginBtn']))
{
if(!filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
$emailError = "Email is not valid";
$errors = 1;
 }

if(!empty($_POST["password"])) {

$passwordError = "Please enter a Password";
$errors = 1;
}

$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$userpassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE emailAddress='$email'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($row['password']==md5($userpassword))
{
 $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];

 header("Location: home.php");
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
    <script>alert('First time visitors, please create an account to play');      </script>
    <?php
  }

  }

  ?>
```

Comment: correct. I don't a user to be able to login with out an account. so ANY blank fields need to report an error.

Comment: Just to clarify - your current code reports as 'password missing' when the password is supplied by the user. The test is reversed from what it should be.

Comment: dang it. What would I need to do to reverse that?.... I see you removed the ! from if (empty($_POST[''password"]))

Comment: Seriously, It will work correctly by just removing the '!', which means 'not'. So, `empty($password)` means blank,  not there, null etc. '!empty($password)' means it must have something useful in it. [empty — Determine whether a variable is empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: I just have to say, if a user is allowed to login with blank credentials, something is seriously wrong. On top of that, PHP now has a future proof built in function for encrypting passwords as opposed to md5.

Comment: @VIDesignz, no - the code supplied by the OP is incorrect and was trying to explain how to fix it - in comments. ;-/ You are perfectly correct with your comment.

Comment: @RyanVincent Yeah, I wasn't saying your suggestions were wrong at all...just there is way bigger issues with the OPs script besides checking for an empty variable, haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client Side validation such as JavaScript and HTML5 can be turned off or directly edited via the browser. Always use server side validation as the final authority.

Also, When checking login credentials you need to do a combination check in the where clause.
`WHERE username ='$u_user' AND password = '$u_pass'`

This is especially the case when allowing the reuse of controlling columns (username, email). Passwords are not always unique.

In the OP's case the lookup on the email only could return multiple results.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('config.php');
IF (isset($_SESSION['user'])!="") { header("Location: home.php"); }

IF (isset($_POST['loginBtn'])) { // the form was submitted

  $err = ""; // default error as empty
  $email= trim($_POST['email']);
  $password = trim($_POST['password']);

  // validation
  IF (empty($email)) { $err .= "Email is empty<br>";
  }ELSE{
    IF (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $err .= "Email is not valid<br>";
    }
  }

  IF (empty($password)) { $err .= "Password is empty<br>"; }

  IF (!empty($err)) {

    // there are errors
    echo("<p>".$err."</p>");

  }ELSE{

    // No errors
    $uemail = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $upass = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($password));
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE emailAddress='$uemail' && password = '$upass'");
    IF ($result) {
      // set session
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];

    }ELSE{
      echo("<p>Email address and or your password was incorrect.<br>If you do not have an account please create one.</p>");
    }

    // Close DB connection
    mysql_close($Your_db_connection);

    // redirect if session is set
    IF (isset($_SESSION['user'])) { header("Location: home.php"); }

  }

}ELSE{
  // form not submitted

}
?>
```

Comment: No problem. If you have any questions let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html5 validation for login form use required attributes for blank input field validation this validation is very easy and user friendly please use this way

Comment: And can be bypassed - so server side validation is always needed.

Comment: Yes server side is needed but if field will be blank then it will return a blank array and then we can show invalid email or password

Comment: We can also use JavaScript validate library for all type of validation its library will work in every browser

Comment: cannot use Javascript, thats all client side. Client side is too easy to bypass. Needs to be server sided like Sorav mentioned. So you're sayin an HTML version will work? It needs to work on many browsers...

Comment: We can also use the server side validation.